# VHDL simulator - can I set a signal or variable when calling from command line?

Tags: vhdl, simulation

I need to set a signal or variable in a VHDL simulation, depending on the
parameters passed in the command line when starting the simulation.
Alternatively, I can read the desired value of this signal or variable from the
environment variable. The solution should be portable between simulators (GHDL, ModelSim etc.) and operating systems (Windows, Linux etc.).
Is there any way to implement it?

**update**

I have found the solution based on VHPI and external C function, however it doesn't seem to be fully portable

http://ygdes.com/GHDL/ghdl_env/

**update2**

Finally I have implemented a solution based on reading data from a file (as suggested by Paebbels):

```
file f_config : text is in "/tmp/config_file.txt";

function config_read
return integer is
variable rl : line;
variable res : integer;
begin
  readline(f_config,rl);
  read(rl,res);
  return res;
end function config_read;
```

Comment: GHDL (0.33, built from trunk) allows you to set the value of a generic from the command line, you can then derive the signal/variable value from the generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple solutions.

1. In addition to Brians comment:
   iSim and xSim can also be initialized with generic values.
2. iSim, xSim and vSim can be controled via TCL scripts. The simulator's TCL library allows you to drive/force signal values. Depending on the library it can be possible to use TCL to access the envitonment variables.
3. GHDL's and vSim's STDIN can be connected to any progams STDOUT. It's possible to read from STDIN in VHDL. Or you can read from any text file in VHDL including pipes.